# Embed a svg object with parameter

Tags: html, object, svg

Who has an idea or a hint

I would like to embed a svg object inside die svg Tag and change this parameter

HTML/SVG (not going on)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Test</title>   
</head>
<body>
<svg width="2000" height="2000">
       <object type="image/svg+xml" data="lamp.svg" style="width: 450px; height:150px;">
          <param name="color" value="yellow" />
       </object>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

SVG File lamp.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="40" height="40">
<title>lamp</title>
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="param(color)" stroke-width=""/>
</svg>
```

With the IMAGE TAG no tag parameter passing is possible.

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" xlink:href="lamp.svg"><param name="color" value="yellow" /></image>
```

Answer (score 13):

Currently browsers don't support passing parameters this way, though there's an  [SVG Parameters spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/) being developed by W3C. The examples in the spec use [a script](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/param.js) to emulate support for the feature.

Note: the shim `param.js` [goes in the SVG file](http://www.mixed-up.com/markb/Web/CustomSVG/proscons.html), not the html file:

e.g.,

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="68" height="68">
<rect x="10" y="10" height="48" width="48" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="param(color) red">
</rect>
<rect x="29" y="0" height="10" width="10" fill="black"></rect>
<text x="24" y="46" fill="param(text) black" style="font-size:32px;"
  content-value="param(number) 1">1</text>

<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="param.js" /> 

</svg>
```

Comment: Any changes to this since 2011?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing changed browser-wise.

Comment: How can I specify param value in document embeding svg? The script looks for params only in the svg file...

Comment: Probably as a url parameter followed after svg document path.