# How to fill rating SVG stars based on average number?

Tags: php, html, css, svg

I am trying to make a rating system with PHP which is working fine but what I want to achieve now is to take into account decimal numbers.

EX: an average of 1.8 will display 2 filled SVG stars which I don't want.
I want now the SVG stars to be filled according to the average

```
<?php
    $averageRating = round($average, 0);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $ratingClass = "<span class='star'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24' increment='0.01'><linearGradient id='hxvf2a' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'><stop offset='0%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop> <stop offset='0%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop></linearGradient> <polygon points='19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74' fill='url(#hxvf2a)' style='color: #hxvf2a;'></polygon></svg></span>";
        if($i <= $averageRating) {
            $ratingClass = "<span  class='star'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24' increment='0.01'><linearGradient id='fm21u' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'><stop offset='100%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop> <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop></linearGradient> <polygon points='19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74' fill='url(#fm21u)'></polygon></svg></span>";
}
?>
    <?= $ratingClass; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You'd probably need to fill them with a linearGradient. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024934/fill-only-half-a-star-with-svg/25025184#25025184

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135761/dynamic-percentage-mask-in-svg-for-5-star-reviews

Answer (score 1):

This could be an example. I place five stars in the same SVG and use them as a mask on a `<rect>`. The width of the `<rect>` controls the value. So, here 75% out of 100%.

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 120 24" >
  <symbol id="star">
    <polygon fill="white" points="19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74"></polygon>
  </symbol>
  <mask id="stars">
    <use href="#star" transform="translate(0 0)"/>
    <use href="#star" transform="translate(24 0)"/>
    <use href="#star" transform="translate(48 0)"/>
    <use href="#star" transform="translate(72 0)"/>
    <use href="#star" transform="translate(96 0)"/>
  </mask>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="75%" height="100%" fill="orange" mask="url(#stars)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to create each star based on percent.
I suggest you to set full , semi full and empty star separately.

i.e:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
        $average=1.2;
        $averageint = (int) ($average);
        $averagefloat = abs($average - $averageint);
        $percent = $averagefloat * 100;
        $ratingClassFull = '';
        $ratingClassEmpty = '';
        $ratingClassPercent='';
    for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if($i <= $averageint) {
            $ratingClassFull .= "<span  class='star'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24' increment='0.01'><linearGradient id='fm21u' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'><stop offset='100%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop> <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop></linearGradient> <polygon points='19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74' fill='url(#fm21u)'></polygon></svg></span>";
       }else{
       $ratingClassEmpty .= "<span class='star'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24' increment='0.01'><linearGradient id='hxvf2a' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'><stop offset='0%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop> <stop offset='0%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop></linearGradient> <polygon points='19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74' fill='url(#hxvf2a)' style='color: #hxvf2a;'></polygon></svg></span>";
       }
       if($averagefloat > 0){
        $ratingClassPercent = "<span  class='star'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24' increment='0.01'>
        <linearGradient id='floatStar' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'>
        <stop offset='".$percent."%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop> 
        <stop offset='100%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop>
        </linearGradient> 
        <polygon points='19.63,7.39,18.58,7.23,17.53,7.06,16.48,6.9,15.77,6.29,15.32,5.33,14.87,4.37,14.42,3.41,13.74,2.6,12.8,2.12,11.75,2.01,10.74,2.3,9.91,2.95,9.36,3.86,8.92,4.82,8.47,5.78,8.02,6.75,7.03,6.98,5.98,7.14,4.93,7.3,3.89,7.51,2.97,8.03,2.32,8.86,2.02,9.87,2.1,10.93,2.56,11.87,3.28,12.65,4.02,13.41,4.76,14.18,5.49,14.94,5.33,15.99,5.16,17.04,4.99,18.08,4.85,19.13,5.03,20.17,5.58,21.07,6.42,21.71,7.44,21.99,8.49,21.86,9.44,21.39,10.36,20.88,11.29,20.36,12.22,20.09,13.15,20.6,14.07,21.12,15,21.64,16,21.98,17.05,21.91,18,21.45,18.72,20.68,19.1,19.69,19.09,18.64,18.92,17.59,18.76,16.54,18.59,15.49,18.85,14.58,19.59,13.82,20.33,13.06,21.06,12.29,21.7,11.45,21.99,10.43,21.88,9.38,21.41,8.44,20.62,7.74' fill='url(#floatStar)'></polygon></svg></span>";
       }
       }
       
       $ratings = $ratingClassFull.$ratingClassPercent.$ratingClassEmpty;
       
        
        

            
?>
    <?= $ratings; ?>



</body>
</html>
```

**output of code:**
[image: output of code:]

Answer (score 0):

Taking Milad's code and simplifying using 2 solid stars without gradients and one with a solid line gradient the percentage of the last star is more clear:

```
  <?PHP
  $average = 4.2;
  $whole = floor($average);   // 4
  $fraction = $average - $whole; // .2
  $averagefloat = abs($average); //4.2
  $percent = $fraction * 100;
  $ratingClassFull = '';
  $ratingClassEmpty = '';
  $ratingClassPercent = '';

  for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if($i <= $averagefloat) {
    // full gold star
    $ratingClassFull .= "
    <span class='star'>
      <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18' increment='0.01'>
        <polygon points='8.94 0 11.05 6.49 17.88 6.49 12.35 10.51 14.46 17 8.94 12.99 3.41 17 5.52 10.51 0 6.49 6.83 6.49 8.94 0' fill='#fdb813'></polygon>
      </svg>
    </span>";

    } else {
      // empty grey star
      $ratingClassEmpty .= "

      <span class='star'>
        <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18' increment='0.01'>
          <polygon points='8.94 0 11.05 6.49 17.88 6.49 12.35 10.51 14.46 17 8.94 12.99 3.41 17 5.52 10.51 0 6.49 6.83 6.49 8.94 0' fill='#bdbdbd' ></polygon>
        </svg>
      </span>";

    }
      // fill with the percentage of the fractions ie. 3.25 would fill 25% of the last star
      if ($averagefloat > 0) {
        $ratingClassPercent = "
        <span class='star'>
          <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='18' width='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18' increment='0.01'>
            <linearGradient id='floatStar' x1='0' x2='100%' y1='0' y2='0'>
            <stop offset='0' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop>
            <stop offset='" . $percent . "%' stop-color='#fdb813'></stop>
            <stop offset='" . $percent . "%' stop-color='#bdbdbd'></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <polygon points='8.94 0 11.05 6.49 17.88 6.49 12.35 10.51 14.46 17 8.94 12.99 3.41 17 5.52 10.51 0 6.49 6.83 6.49 8.94 0' fill='url(#floatStar)'></polygon>
          </svg>
        </span>";
      }
    }

    $ratings = $ratingClassFull.$ratingClassPercent.$ratingClassEmpty;
    echo $ratings;?>
```

Result: [image]